# How to promote html5 mobile app

Tags: html, web-applications, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am working on a HTML5 Cross-device Mobile optimized App 
([podcaster.mobi](http://www.podcaster.mobi)).  I submitted it to [OpenAppMkt](http://openappmkt.com/app/504ce8062a67710002007931/Podcaster.mobi) where i got good reviews (4 out of 5 stars in average of 6 ratings), but otherwise have done little to advertise it, other than telling friends about it and creating a Facebook Page (http://www.facebook.com/pages/Podcastermobi/104949029662395)

Does anyone have any experience in building a user-base for Mobile Web Apps? It seems like the lack of presence in the native App stores / markets is a big limitation with HTML5 WebApps - One i would love to find a nice solution for!